# Nuxt 3 trouble after build project

Tags: nuxtjs3

Can you help me to solve problem with my project?

The Problem.
After build project does not work html5 video on MacOS < 15 version and iOS < 15 version. Path is ok, there is no 404 error, but video don’t work.
In development mode video is work.
Are you know something about this problem?
Can you see this [repo](https://github.com/klyuk88/aronovlaw-client/) ?

Video is located in components/main-page/ Screen.vue - line 94

I tried launch Nuxt2 project. Video is work well.
I tried load video from strapi. Its doesn't work in production.((

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Got an error in the console on the production server?

Comment: Where do you host your various apps too?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I posted the video on another server and it worked. But the video still doesn't play from the assets folder.
There were no errors in the console.

Comment: How do you import it? Got any fancy router/nuxt configuration/reverse proxy or alike?